# Xcode seems not to reuse compiled files

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I have a CMake project that consist of many applications. Most of those applications are test apps running...well...tests.

I spotted a strange behavior which starts to drive me nuts: when I compile an application Xcode recompiles every file that was changed. That's normal. But when I switch to another application it recompiles even those `.o` files that was compiled in the previous compilation.

I don't know if this is normal on Mac, but I use my project also on Linux and MS Windows, and there if I compile one app and switch to another app then the compiler doesn't recompile a file that was compiled before during compilation of another app.

Is there a way to setup the same behavior with Xcode?

I'm using:

- Xcode 15.0.1
- CMake 3.28.1
- Clang++ 15.0.0.15000040

My code is written in C++ and uses ObjC-Runtime to communicate with the OS (it is a GUI app)

Comment: How do you "switch to another application"? Perhaps each "application" have it's own project output directory (where things like object files are stored)?

Comment: I think it is not the case as I spitted my app into many modules (using `add_library` CMake command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was the problem: each application indeed was contained in separate directories with all its dependencies put inside them.

To solve the issue it is as simple as to add:

```
if(APPLE)
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS OFF)
endif()
```

at the very end of the (important!) toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` file.